# Two txtbox autocomplete using data{keyword:keyword} $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am having two textboxes and I want them to autocomplete from two different column from `mysql database` , I am getting the result for first one but when i am using the same code for second one, its not working. 
I am calling my `autocomplet()` on `onkeyup` in html

**jQuery :**

```
    function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#clientname').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#clientlist_id').show();
                $('#clientlist_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#clientlist_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#clientname').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#clientlist_id').hide();
}

function autocomplete() {
    var min_lengthstaff = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var input = $('#staff').val();
    if (input.length >= min_lengthstaff) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'autocompletephpcode.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {input:input},
            success:function(data){
                $('#stafflist_id').show();
                $('#stafflist_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#stafflist_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_itemstaff(items) {
    // change input value
    $('#staff').val(items);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#stafflist_id').hide();
}
```

**ajax_refresh.php:**

```
<?php
// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=entry', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}
 //for client name
$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdata WHERE client_name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $client_name = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['client_name']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['client_name']).'\')">'.$client_name.'</li>';
}

?>
```

autocompletephpcode.php:

```
<?php
// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=entry', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}
 //for staff name
$pdo = connect();
$input = '%'.$_POST['input'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdata WHERE staff LIKE (:input) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':input', $input, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $staff = str_replace($_POST['input'], '<b>'.$_POST['input'].'</b>', $rs['staff']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_itemstaff(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['staff']).'\')">'.$staff.'</li>';
}

?>
```

this is my html-

```
<form id="dataentry" action="ajax_refresh.php" method="post" role="form" >
 <div class="input_container">
 <label for="Clientname">Client Name</label></br>
 <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" onkeyup="autocomplet()" />
 <ul id="clientlist_id"></ul>
</div>
</form>
<form action="autocompletephpcode.php" method="post" role="form">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
   <div class="input_container">
 <label for="Staff">Staff</label></br>
 <input type="text" name="staff" id="staff" onkeyup="autocomplete()" />
 <ul id="stafflist_id"></ul>
</div>
```

The same code for `client_name` is not working !

Comment: when i write the same code for staff_name and replace client name in the code with staff name ,its not working .i just want to know if i can use data{keyword:keyword }for staff as well? what does keyword before and after colon stands for in my code?

Comment: I would use classes instead of ids `$('#clientname').val(item);`.

Comment: does tht make any diff?

Comment: this code is working exactly the way i want it to but when i implement the same code for staff name its showing me error -it says "undefined index:keyword"

Comment: In your code? Of course! You don't have to write 2 times the same code.

Comment: What exactly is your error message?

Comment: then what should i do? i m actually new to ajax

Comment: actually i am getting the list of staff name as well as client name in client textbox and when i type in staff textbox it is not autosuggesting anything

Comment: Can you show me your code for staff_name?

Comment: function autocomplete() {
 var min_length = 0; 
 var keyword = $('#staff').val();
 if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'autocompletephpcode.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: {keyword:keyword},
   success:function(data){
    $('#stafflist_id').show();
    $('#stafflist_id').html(data);
   }
  });
 } else {
  $('#stafflist_id').hide();
 }
}
function set_item(item) {
 // change input value
 $('#staff').val(item);
 // hide proposition list
 $('#stafflist_id').hide();
}

Comment: and i created a different php file for the php code to retrieve staff name list from database and it goes like-

Comment: <?php
 {
$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdata WHERE staff LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
 // put in bold the written text
 $staff = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['staff']);
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['staff']).'\')">'.$staff.'</li>';
}
?>

Comment: is it right that you have 2 set_item functions?

Comment: it is showing the selected option from client autocomplete in staff textbox

Comment: actually not. i would say you have declared 2 times the same function in your code.

Comment: but i changed it ..still not working

Comment: please edit your post and show both codes for `client_name` and `staff_name`.

Comment: can i use anything else instead of keyword:keyword in data in $.ajax

Comment: yes of course. first parameter is your post parameter which you use in your php and the second parameter is the value of it.

Comment: your html is not valid. that could cause the problem.

Comment: whats the problem with tht?

Comment: you are closing a div in your second form right after opening it.

Comment: i dnt think tht has anything to do with tht..cause my client textbox is working fine ..n i changed tht div as well ..still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do so:

**jQuery**

```
function autocomplete_client() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#clientname').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh_client.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#clientlist_id').show();
                $('#clientlist_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#clientlist_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item_client(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#clientname').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#clientlist_id').hide();
}

function autocomplete_staff() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#staff').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh_staff.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#stafflist_id').show();
                $('#stafflist_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#stafflist_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item_staff(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#staff').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#stafflist_id').hide();
}
```

**ajax_refresh_client.php**

```
// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=entry', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}
//for client name
$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdata WHERE client_name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $client_name = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['client_name']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item_client(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['client_name']).'\')">'.$client_name.'</li>';
}
```

**ajax_refresh_staff.php**

```
// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=entry', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}
//for staff name
$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM newdata WHERE staff LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 10";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $staff = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['staff']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item_staff(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['staff']).'\')">'.$staff.'</li>';
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="input_container">
    <label for="Clientname">Client Name</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" onkeyup="autocomplete_client()" />
    <ul id="clientlist_id"></ul>
</div>
<div class="input_container">
    <label for="Staff">Staff</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="staff" id="staff" onkeyup="autocomplete_staff()" />
    <ul id="stafflist_id"></ul>
</div>
```

Make sure to clear your cache. This code could be cleaner, but it'll work.

Comment: it worked thanks alot..but what was the problem with my code? anyways thanks @Huelfe

Comment: as is said. your html was not valid. ;)